# Find device's MAC address connected through USB

Tags: usb-device

I'm interested in finding the MAC address of a device (in this case an ESP8266) connected through an USB serial to my computer. Is there a linux command to achieve that? I tried with `dmesg` or `lsusb` but without luck.

I'm on Arch Linux, Kernel "5.2.6-arch1-1-ARCH"

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the serial port of the ESP8266 and run this command:

```
AT+CIPSTAMAC?
```

You can find the serial port using this command:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

Or this command:

```
setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123]
```

You may find a good list of programs to connect to the serial port at [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/).

Comment: Nice! I was looking for the AT command but I couldn't find good documentation, and what I did find didn't have anything for MAC. Could you link the source?

Comment: Then upvote my answer and accept it as the correct answer! This is my first activity here. The source is: https://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/26/esp8266-at-command-reference/#AT+CIPSTAMAC

Comment: Upvoted, but you'll have to wait for OP to accept

Comment: Thanks. I saw your name on the other answer and mistakenly thought you were the OP. I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can get MAC addresses from connected network adapters with `ifconfig`

However, I don't think you'll be able to do this for your serial device, because it would not show up as a network adapter device. You would need to send the appropriate commands over serial to get the MAC address, which are specific to this particular device.

You can probably upload an [Arduino sketch that prints the MAC address](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/04/09/esp8266-get-mac-address/), which would display the address over Serial. The ESP8266WiFi library handles the heavy lifting.

Here's the sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup(){

   Serial.begin(115200);
   delay(500);

   Serial.println();
   Serial.print("MAC: ");
   Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());

}

void loop(){}
```